# Javascript Return and if/else

Tags: javascript

For the following code, I keep getting `Scissors` back for `alert`. I am not sure what am I doing wrong here.

```
var computerChoice = Math.random();

var newChoice = function (computerChoice) {
    if (computerChoice <= 0.34) {
        var newChoice = "rock";
        return newChoice;
    } else if ((computerChoice >= 0.35) && (computerChoice <= 0.66)) {
        var newChoice = "paper";
        return newChoice;
    } else {
        var newChoice = "scissors";
        return newChoice;
    }

}
var newerChoice = newChoice();
alert(newerChoice);
```

Comment: You are not passing an argument to `newChoice` when you call it, hence `computerChoice` (the parameter of the function) is `undefined`. `undefined <= 0.34` is `false`, same for the other comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing an argument to `newChoice` when you call it, hence the value of the **parameter** `computerChoice` is `undefined`. `undefined <= 0.34` is `false`, same for the other comparisons.

Two possible solutions are:

- Remove the parameter from the function, so that `computerChoice` refers to the global variable. Currently the parameter *shadows* the outer variable with the same name.
- (better) Call the function with an argument.

---

[Learn more about functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

Comment: There is also third solution to generate the number inside the function, so nothing needs to be passed: 

`var newChoice = function() { var computerChoice = Math.random();`

Comment: Thanks Felix, completely forgot about the passing the argument. And referring to global variable and undefined helped very much-:)

Comment: @MaxZoom: True. I didn't mean to imply that there are only these two solutions.

Comment: @Max: Thanks for the third solution, I just ran it for conceptually understanding it. And of course it worked-:) The variable computerChoice was incorrectly put in there due to typing, nonetheless thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @MaxZoom, I have edited `var computerChoice` to `var newChoice` in the first `if` statment.

Answer (score 1):

The `computerChoice` argument to the newChoice method is `undefined` as nothing is passed in the call `newChoice()`.
If you want to pass previously generated number, you could do that as below:

```js
var computerChoice = Math.random();

var newChoice = function(computerChoice) {
  if (computerChoice <= 0.34) {
    return "rock";
  } else if ((computerChoice >= 0.35) && (computerChoice <= 0.66)) {
    return "paper";
  } else {
    return "scissors";
  }
}
var newerChoice = newChoice(computerChoice);
alert(newerChoice);
```

Comment: "method is null" -> "method is undefined"

Comment: Sorry, I was (badly) quoting part your answer. The argument is not null, it is undefined.

Comment: Why should I? Maybe I still haven't expressed myself clearly: You wrote: *"The `computerChoice` argument to the newChoice method is null."* However, that is incorrect. When no value is passed, the value of the argument is `undefined`, not `null`. Hence it is more correct to say *"The `computerChoice` argument to the newChoice method has the value `undefined`."*

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a bit of confusion over variables and parameters.  Here's some working code...

```
var newChoice = function (choice) {
    if (choice <= 0.34) {
        return "rock";
    } else if (choice <= 0.66) {
        return "paper";
    } else {
        return "scissors";
    }
};

var computerChoice = Math.random();
var newerChoice = newChoice(computerChoice);
alert(newerChoice);
```

The value that is passed into `newChoice` is the parameter `choice`.  I trimmed out the `&&` as they're not required.  If choice is not <= 0.34 then it must be greater than 0.34, so that check is not required later.

`computerChoice` is a random value variable that is passed as a parameter to the function.

Here's a working fiddle example...

http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/0dfhoa63/

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually passing in `computerChoice` as a variable to the function despite declaring it as an argument. Instead of `var newerChoice = newChoice();` do `var newerChoice = newChoice(computerChoice);`. I think the function will be looking for computerChoice as an argument instead of looking at the earlier declaration. Look up variable scope in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your `newChoice` function is expecting a parameter. Therefore you ened to give it one

```
var newerChoice = newChoice(computerChoice);
```

Also, I believe that in the first if statement, you wanted to have `newChoice = "rock";`, not `computerChoice = "rock";`

Answer (score -1):

```
var newerChoice = newChoice(Math.random());
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer.

Comment: The function expects a parameter to be passed in.

Answer (score -1):

Have a good look at this line:

```
var newChoice = function (computerChoice) {
```

You created a function called `newChoice`, and require an argument called `computerChoice`. Now let's see how you execute that function later on.

```
var newerChoice = newChoice();
```

You execute the function `newChoice`, but you did not pass `computerChoice` as an argument this time.

**The solution**

What you can do is fairly easy. Change the following:

```
var newChoice = function (computerChoice) {
```

Into

```
var newChoice = function () {
```

And make it so that your `newChoice` function generates a new value for `computerChoice`, by adding `computerChoice = Math.random();` to your function. Like this:

```js
var computerChoice = Math.random();

var newChoice = function () {
computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice <= 0.34) {
        var computerChoice = "rock";
        return newChoice;
    } else if ((computerChoice >= 0.35) && (computerChoice <= 0.66)) {
        var newChoice = "paper";
        return newChoice;
    } else {
        var newChoice = "scissors";
        return newChoice;
    }

}
var newerChoice = newChoice();
alert(newerChoice);
```

Comment: I learn as I go, so I'd appreciate it if someone elaborates why I'm being downvoted when they do downvote me. Thanks in advance folks.